# SHR on int64 does not return expected result

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, int64

I'm porting some C# code to Delphi (XE5). The C# code has code like this:

```
long t = ...
...                
t = (t >> 25) + ...
```

I translated this to

```
t: int64;
...
t := (t shr 25) + ...
```

Now I see that Delphi (sometimes) calculates wrong values for shifting negative t's, e.g.:

```
-170358640930559629 shr 25
Windows Calculator: -5077083139
C# code: -5077083139

Delphi: 
-170358640930559629 shr 25               = 544678730749 (wrong)
```

For this example, -1*((-t shr 25)+1) gives the correct value in Delphi.

For other negative values of t a simple typecast to integer seems to give the correct result:

```
integer(t shr 25)
```

I am at my limit regarding binary operations and representations, so I would appreciate any help with simply getting the same results in Delphi like in C# and Windows calculator.

Comment: The problem is explained in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348540/what-is-a-equivalent-of-delphi-shl-in-c#comment6042256_5348558

Comment: Your `-1*((-Value shr Bits)+1)` fails when `Value = -4` and `Bits = 1`. It returns `-3` instead of `-2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [article](http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/2009/shift-right-delphi-vs-c/) linked in Filipe's [answer](http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/2009/shift-right-delphi-vs-c/) (which states the reason to be Delphi carrying out a `shr` as opposed to others doing a `sar`), here's my take on this:

```
function CalculatorRsh(Value: Int64; ShiftBits: Integer): Int64;
begin
  Result := Value shr ShiftBits;
  if (Value and $8000000000000000) > 0 then
    Result := Result or ($FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF shl (64 - ShiftBits));
end;
```

Comment: +1. This works great. When ´Value´ is negative, it replaces the leftmost `0` bits put by `shr` with the correct `1` bits. The `and` condition is equivalent to `Value < 0`.

Comment: @JRL - Thanks! Do you think making the 'negative' test more readable would be good here? After all it involves some bit shifts..

Comment: Would the same function for 32-bit integers look like this?

function CalculatorRsh(value:integer; ShiftBits : integer): integer;

begin

 Result := Value shr ShiftBits;
  if (Value and $80000000) > 0 then
    Result := Result or ($FFFFFFFF shl (32 - ShiftBits));
end;

Comment: @user - Tried it now, it gives a range check error on $FFFFFFFF (if range checking is on), cast it to an integer, or replace with -1.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/2009/shift-right-delphi-vs-c/), the way C and Delphi treat Shr is different. Not meaning to point fingers, but C's >> isn't really a shr, it's actually a sar.
Anyways, the only workaround that I've found is doing your math manually. Here's an example:

```
function SAR(a, b : int64): int64;
begin
  result := round(a / (1 shl b));
end;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your SAR function seems to be of by one:

SAR(-1841198311509,25) returns -54871, while Windows Calc returns -54872.

Comment: Just changed the function, take a look and see what you think. It's edited at the answer.

Comment: @GJ. - See revision history, and the first comment to the answer.

Comment: Both `round(a / (1 shl b))` and `a div (1 shl b))` fail when `a = -5` and `b = 1`. Both return `-2` instead of `-3`.

Comment: That article is a poor source. C's `>>` is *implementation-defined* for negative operands, so it's unhelpful to compare it with Delphi's shift operator. Better to compare with C#, as the question did.